# Why $f$ restricted to the set of its discontinuities $E_0$ is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to answer the following question:

Suppose a function $f$ has a measurable domain and is continuous except at a finite number of points. Is $f$ necessarily measurable?

And I found this answer online:

"Let $E$ denote the (Lebesgue) measurable domain of $f$ and define $$E_0 = \{x \in E| f \text{ is not continuous at } x \}$$

Since $E_0$ is finite, $m(E_0) = 0$ and $f$ is measurable on $E_0.$ By proposition $3,$ $f$ is measurable on $E \sim E_0$ as it is continuous on this set. We conclude from proposition $5(ii)$ that $f$ is measurable on $E.$"

**My question is:**

Why $f$ restricted to the set of its discontinuities $E_0$ is measurable? by what theorem, proposition or logical justification?

Comment: Let $g = f|_{E_0} : E_0 \to \mathbb{R}$. The pre-image $g^{-1}(S) \subseteq E_0$ of any measurable $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a finite set, and hence measurable. Thus $g$ is measurable by definition.

Comment: @joeb why are you sure that the preimage is a finite set? and why we needed $S$ to be measurable in $\mathbb R$

Comment: In this case, $E_0$ is a finite set, so all its subsets are also finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $E_0$ is finite and therefore discrete, the restriction of the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets to $E_0$ is $\mathcal P(E_0)$. Therefore, any function defined on $E_0$ is measurable.

**Edit**

If $(X,\mathcal A)$ is a measurable space (ie $X$ is a set and $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$) and $Y\subset X$ is a subset, then $Y$ is canonically a measurable space $(Y,\mathcal A|_Y)$ where the restriction of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$ to the subset $Y$ is defined as :
$$\mathcal A|_Y=  \{Y\cap W:W\in\mathcal A\}$$
If $X$ is a topological space and $\mathcal A = \mathcal B(X)$ is its Borel $\sigma$-algebra, then $\mathcal A|_Y = \mathcal B(Y)$ (ie the restriction of a Borel algebra is the Borel algebra of the topological subspace).

Comment: Sorry, I did not get what you said here "the restriction of the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets to $E_0$ is $\mathcal P(E_0)$" could you provide more details please?